# Pushbullet API from cURL - invalid request

Tags: pushbullet

I'm working on an app using [Pushbullet's API](https://docs.pushbullet.com/http/), but I'm running into odd errors when running through the sample code at https://docs.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/.

I'm executing the following cURL command (in Windows):

```
curl -k -u <MY_API_KEY>: -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "Note Title", "body": "Note Body"}'
```

...but it keeps generating the following error:

```
{"error": {"type":"invalid_request","message":"The param 'type' has an invalid value.","param":"type","cat":"\u003e:3"}}
```

It also produces this error:
[image]

The other commands for the other endpoints in the documentation work fine...it's just this one.

Got any suggestions? Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like windows doesn't support those kinds of quotes on the command line. Here's an example that works:

`curl https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes -X POST -u <access token>: --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "{\"type\": \"note\", \"title\":\"Note Title\", \"body\": \"Note Body\"}"`

I think I'm going to try to replace the curl examples with something that has less confusing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I don't really know why, but the cURL command wasn't working through the DOS prompt, and also wasn't working using the [Postman REST client for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), but I got it working in the [DHC extension for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en). The trick was setting the **Authorization** header to "Basic", which resolves the [Pushbullet access token](https://www.pushbullet.com/account) to some other form, and makes a successful the HTTP request.

Hope this helps someone down the road if they run into this on Windows!